# Excel Com Object using AutoHotKey randomly invisible

Tags: autohotkey

I use below script to get Imagepath from `IrfanView` and go to `Excel` cell that contains Imagepath.

```
;Excel Column name that contains imagename
ImageColumn=A
;handle to running application
try XL := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
; Create COM If no Excel is running
Catch {
    MsgBox % "no existing Excl object:  Need to create one"
XL := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
}
;Get ImagePath from Free image viewer Irfanview image properties dialog
ControlGetText, ImagePath, Edit3, IrfanView - Image properties
;And close the dialog
PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, IrfanView - Image properties
;Loop until Excel activate to workaround for excel randomly not get active state
Loop
 {
     WinActivate, ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
     IfWinActive, ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
        Break
     Sleep 200
 }
;Get Excel activecell
DataColNum:=XL.Activecell.Column
;Make COM obj visible to ensure visibility
XL.Application.ActiveWindow.Visible := 1
;Find ImageName in the column
XL.Application.ActiveSheet.Range(XL.Cells(Floor(XL.Application.WorkSheetFunction.Match(ImagePath,XL.Application.ActiveSheet.Range(ImageColumn . ":" . ImageColumn),0)),DataColNum).Address).Activate
```

But this script randomly misses to make the Excel window visible to our eyes i.e. Activecell still receives input from keyboard but the window is invisible.